# What is this sushi?

Tags: sushi, japanese-cuisine, food-identification

I'm trying to identify what kind of sushi is featured at the bottom right of this picture of a display of what seems to be mainly nigiri sushi. The yellow, spongy looking one. Can anyone name what kind of fish / meat / other that is?

[image: sushi with tamago]
<sub>[(from Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:2007feb-sushi-odaiba-manytypes.jpg)</sub>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That item in the bottom right is [Tamago](http://justonecookbook.com/blog/recipes/tamagoyaki-japanese-rolled-omelette/) nigiri, a slice of omelette on top of seasoned rice.

Comment: Just egg, but it's *STILL* $7 a pair!

Comment: @Jolenealaska - There's a lot of technique in that little omelette. It's prepared with ground mountain yam in place of water or milk for one, and cooked in a particular way that involves ultrathin layers of egg rolled into a tamagoyaki, requiring a special makiyakinabe pan. Like the french crepe, tamagoyaki can be either pedestrian or the height of sophistication, and it's down to technique.

Comment: @RISwampYankee Well, maybe I'll try it someday, after I'd had my fill of eel and SMT. YUM!

Comment: @Jolenealaska : think of it as the dessert at the end of the meal.  It's also useful to know to ask for as a westerner who's not used to Japanese breakfasts.

Comment: Mastering tamagoyaki http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTIcJ_tdEJM

Comment: @belisarius - That was cool. Now I'm going to have to try it next time I go for sushi. I go through a lot of Groupons that way. It also looks like fun to try to approximate at home.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Indeed! Bon appétit!

Comment: @RISwampYankee : From my experience, I'd wager that the vast majority of sushi bars in the US and Canada use pre-made/frozen Tamagoyaki.

Comment: @Didgeridrew EEEW! We have about a gazillion sushi bars in Anchorage, I'll never visit them all. That might be a good question to ask over the phone to separate the wheat from the chaff, "Do you make your own Tamagoyaki?"